# Solving a second-order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving the following equation:

$$2xy'' + y' - 2y = 0$$ with a substitution. Here's what I did:

**divide the equation by $2x$**:

$$y'' + \frac{1}{2x}y' - \frac{1}{x}y = 0$$

Now, we let $y = u(x) \cdot z, z=z(x)$

This is a method of transforming the y variable where we obtain the following equation:

$$z'' + (\frac{2u'}{u} + p)z' + (\frac{u''}{u} + p\frac{u'}{u} + q)z = 0,  p=p(x), q=q(x)$$

Where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are coefficients of $y'$ and $y$ respectively, after we divide it by $2x$.

Next, we choose a function $u(x)$ so the coefficient of $z'$ is zero. Thus, $$u(x) = e^{-\int{\frac{p(x)}{2}dx}}$$

In my case, $u(x) = \frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{4}}$. Next, we find $u'$ and $u''$ and plug them into the following equation:

$$z'' + (\frac{u''}{u} + p\frac{u'}{u} + q)z = 0$$, where $$ p=p(x), q=q(x)$$

To get another equation which is hopefully more easily solvable. **However**, in my case, I get $$z''+(\frac{3-16x}{16x^2})z=0$$ which I have no clue how to solve, which leads me to think I have chosen the wrong substitution. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$2xy'' + y' - 2y = 0$$
Divide by $2\sqrt x$:
$$\sqrt xy'' +\dfrac { y'}{2\sqrt x} - \dfrac y {\sqrt x}= 0$$
$$(\sqrt x y')'-\dfrac y {\sqrt x}=0$$
$$\dfrac {d(\sqrt x y')}{d \sqrt x}\dfrac 1 {2\sqrt x}-\dfrac y {\sqrt x}=0$$
$$\dfrac {d(\sqrt x y')}{d \sqrt x}-2y =0$$
$$\dfrac {d^2y}{d (\sqrt x)^2}-4y =0$$
Note that $y'=\dfrac {dy}{d x}$. Now it's easy to solve.
$$r^2-4= 0 \implies r= \pm 2$$
$$y(x)=c_1 e^{ 2 \sqrt x}+c_2 e^ {-2 \sqrt x}$$